# Christmas tree in Javascript using stars

Tags: javascript

I have this loop problem, I really don't understand why my code doesn't work, I've even draw this on paper and for my logic it looks good but it's not working, please help me.

```js
function drawTree(h) {
  for(var i=0; i<=h; i++){
    var star = '';
    for(var k=0; k<=1; k++){
      star += "  ";
    };
    for(var j=0; j<=i; j++) {
        star += "*";
    };
  };
    console.log(star);
};

drawTree(5);
```

Comment: You only print one line every time, the `console.log` is outside your loop.

Comment: For starters you only call `console.log` once but i dont see any newlines.

Comment: what was the expected result, exactly? If you're looking for a christmas tree, as the title suggests, then you'd need to start new lines in suitable places

Answer (score -1, accepted):

You have to place the **console.log** statement inside first for loop. That should give a half tree. 
If you want correct tree, then pre-pend spaces before star. 
Calculate the center of the number of rows and add spaces before it.

Hope this not an assignment problem.

```js
function drawTree(h) {
  for(var i=0; i<=h; i++){
    var star = '';
    for(var k=0; k<=1; k++){
      star += "  ";
    };
    for(var j=0; j<=i; j++) {
        star += "*";
    };
    console.log(star);
  };

};

drawTree(5);
```

Comment: why is this the accepted answer? It only draws half a tree. https://stackoverflow.com/a/49875805/5947043 is a much better answer IMHO (and seemingly the opinions of the others who upvoted it)

Answer (score 5):

See comments in the code for changes.

```js
function drawTree(h) {
  for(var i=0; i<=h; i++){
    var star = '';
    //Changed to start high then decrease
    for(var k = 1; k <= h - i; k++){
      //shortened to one space
      star += " ";
    };
    for(var j=0; j<=i; j++) {
        //Added space so there is an odd number
        //of symbols and the star above fits
        //the space
        star += " *";
    };
    //Moved into the loop
    console.log(star);
  };
};

drawTree(5);
```

Note that the code can be substantially shortened using `String.prototype.repeat`:

```js
function drawTree(h) {
  for (var i = 0; i <= h; i++){
    console.log(" ".repeat(h - i) + " *".repeat(i + 1));
  };
};

drawTree(5);
```

Also note that your example produces a base line with six stars for a call of `drawTree(5)`. I am unsure whether that is intended. The code above reproduces said behavior, editing it to show a line less should not be too hard.

Answer (score 1):

```js
function drawTree(h) {
  for (var i = 0; i < h; i++) {
    var star = '';
    var space = (h - i);
    if (i == 0) {
      star += ' '.repeat(space + 1) + '\n';
    }
    star += ' '.repeat(space + 1);
    var zero = 2 * i + 1;
    star += '*'.repeat(zero);
    console.log(star);
  }
}
drawTree(5);
```

Answer (score 0):

You’re re-setting it each line, but printing it only at the end.

Move `console.log(star);` to the end of the first loop.

Answer (score 0):

Just for fun:

```js
const tree = ({height: h = 5, stumpHeight: sh = 2, branchChar: bc = '*', emptyChar: ec = ' ', stumpChar: sc = '#'} = {}) => [
  ... Array .from ({length: h}, (_, n) => ec .repeat (h - n - 1) + bc.repeat (2 * n + 1) + ec .repeat (h - n - 1)),
  ... Array .from ({length: sh}, () => ec .repeat (h - 1) + sc + ec .repeat (h - 1)),
] .join ('\n')


console .log (tree ())
console .log (tree ({height: 6, emptyChar: '_'}))
console .log (tree ({height: 12, stumpHeight: 3, stumpChar: '@'}))
console .log (tree ({branchChar: '#'}))
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper {max-height: 100% !important; top: 0}
```

Because, you know, that's how all those JS 101 instructors expect it to be coded.

Answer (score 0):

```
function drawTree(n) {
      let tag = "#";               
      for (let i = 0, j = "#"; i < n; i++) {
        console.log(tag);
        tag = tag + j;
      }
    }

drawTree(10);
```

Comment: Please don't post code-only answers. The main audience, future readers, will be grateful to see explained *why* this answers the question instead of having to infer it from the code. Also, since this is an old question, please explain how it complements the other answers.