# Shorter Way of Prinitng Triangle Patterns JavaScript

Tags: javascript, nested-loops

I'm trying to find a shorter way to print a right-triangle and an isosceles triangle without using that many nested loops. Please help, here is my code so far, it works I just have trouble finding a shorter way to write it:

```js
//right-triangle
let triangleStr = "";
let num = 5;
for (let i = 1; i <= num; i++) {
  for (let j = 0; j < num - i; j++) {
    triangleStr += " ";
  }
  for (let k = 0; k < i; k++) {
    triangleStr += "*";
  }
  triangleStr += "\n";
}
console.log(triangleStr);

//isosceles-triangle
triangleString = "";
for (let i = 1; i <= num; i++) {
  for (let j = 1; j <= num - i; j++) {
    triangleString += " ";
  }
  for (let k = 1; k <= 2 * i - 1; k++) {
    triangleString += "*";
  }
  triangleString += "\n";
}
console.log(triangleString);
```

Comment: This might be better suited for https://codereview.stackexchange.com/

Comment: `const halftree = n => console.log(Array.from({ length: n }, (_, i) => ' '.repeat(n - i - 1) + '*'.repeat(i + 1)).join('\n'));`

Comment: Look at this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68803096/how-to-draw-a-spruce-shape-triangle-in-javascript/68803253#68803253

Comment: PS: this star printing task is typically used around christmas, and talks about christmas trees instead of "triangles", see e.g. a [question from five years ago](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49875606/christmas-tree-in-javascript-using-stars) (linked because i have an ancient old answer in there, and could easily find it - there have been tons of these). Just in case you want to research other solutions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to use only **one loop**, you can use `repeat()` method in **ECMAScript6** or higher.

*For Right triangle:*

```js
const line = 5;
let rightTriangle = "";
for (let l = 1; l <= line ; l++) {
    const indent = line-l;
    rightTriangle += `${" ".repeat(indent)}${"*".repeat(l)}${"\n"}`;
}
console.log(rightTriangle);
```

*For Isosceles triangle:*

```js
const line = 5;
let isoscelesTriangle = "";
for (let l = 1; l <= line ; l++) {
    const indent = line - l;
    isoscelesTriangle += `${" ".repeat(indent)}${"*".repeat(2*l-1)}${"\n"}`;
}
console.log(isoscelesTriangle);
```

Comment: This was a great method of doing it, thank you!